# InnoDB Buffer Pool and Buffer Log

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6, mariadb-10.1

I have been reading too many information about InnoDB parameters, but I still have a doubt. Should "innodb_log_buffer_size" be larger than "innodb_buffer_pool_size"?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! `Should "innodb_log_buffer_size" be larger than "innodb_buffer_pool_size"?` No! Your question should contain lines like "I searched for <innodb_xxxx_buffer_yyyy_size> and I've found a, b and c. Search for "my.cnf" recommendations - what I found after a **short** search is that the former is normally measured in MB and the latter in GB - apart from that, you'll have to provide more information (XXGB RAM, HDD/SSD, OLTP/OLAP...) if you want actual recommendations. These parameters are all interrelated and determining the optimal configuration is an art in itself!

Comment: Dear Verace, thanks for your suggestions. However, I have modified other parameters and my VPS is stable

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is about 70% of available RAM.  This is the most important setting.  It controls the amount of RAM being used for caching, hence it helps speed up most queries.

Leave `innodb_log_buffer_size` at the default given by the install.  This setting is much less important.  It has to do with writing *redo* log entries to disk.  (Cf "transactions")

Comment: Dear Rick, thanks for your reply. I am now measuring the necessary "innodb_buffer_pool_size" value for fine tuning. Concerning "innodb_log_buffer_size", I will leave it to the default value.